# Need help in Building dynamic select query in Mule 4 DW 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have the following query params coming to my API

```
{
    "PERSON_ID": "123456",
    "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE": "2011-12-15T00:00:00",
    "START_DATE": "2011-12-15T00:00:00",
    "END_DATE": "2012-12-15T00:00:00"
}
```

I need to build a different dynamic SQL query based on the input parameters which can be any of the these given below - (either LAST_MODIFIED_DATE or (START_DATE and END_DATE) will be based. But PERSON_ID can be passed any of the other params

```
select * from Person where PERSON_ID = 123456 
select * from Person where LAST_MODIFIED_DATE = 2011-12-15T00:00:00 
select * from Person where PERSON_ID = 123456 and LAST_MODIFIED_DATE = 2011-12-15T00:00:00 
select * from Person where PERSON_ID = 123456 and LAST_MODIFIED_DATE between 2011-12-15T00:00:00 and 2012-12-15T00:00:00
select * from Person where LAST_MODIFIED_DATE between 2011-12-15T00:00:00 and 2012-12-15T00:00:00
or if no query params are passed it will be 
select * from Person
```

my DW logic is not able to cater to this requirement.

Tried below but not able to get the required results. Could you please suggest a recommended approach or best solution

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = {
    "PERSON_ID": "123456",
    "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE": "2011-12-15T00:00:00",
    "START_DATE": "2011-12-15T00:00:00",
    "END_DATE": "2012-12-15T00:00:00"
}
"Select * from Person Where " ++
((data filterObject ((value, key, index) -> (value != null and value != "")) mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {
    (myData : "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE between " ++ (key as String)) if ((key as String) == "START_DATE"),
    (myData : "AND " ++ (key as String)) if ((key as String) == "END_DATE"),
    (myData : (key as String) ++ " = :" ++ (key as String)) if ((key as String) == "PERSON_ID"),
     myData : (key as String) ++ " = :" ++ (key as String)
})).*myData joinBy  " AND ")
```

Later in the DB connector I am setting the above output variable as query in SQL String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very common use case with a lot of possible solutions.
What I like to do is I create an Array with all the conditions as items. Then join them using `joinBy` function with a `' AND '` string to join those condition.

If you follow this the use of [Conditional Elements](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-types#conditional_elements_array) makes the complex and dynamic SQL generation very readable and clear IMO

**Updated the following based on Aled's suggestion to avoid SQL Injection**
For Example

```js
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
fun generateWhereClause(queryParams) = 
    [
        ("PERSON_ID = :PERSON_ID") if(queryParams.PERSON_ID?),
        ("LAST_MODIFIED_DATE = :LAST_MODIFIED_DATE") if(queryParams.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE?),
        ("LAST_MODIFIED_DATE >= :START_DATE") if(queryParams.START_DATE?),
        ("LAST_MODIFIED_DATE <= :END_DATE") if(queryParams.END_DATE?),
    ] joinBy " AND "
---
'SELECT * FROM person WHERE $(generateWhereClause(vars.queryParams))'
```

This will generate a parameterized SQL Statement, and you can pass your query parameters as the input parameter in the `select` operation.

```xml
<db:select config-ref="dbConfig">
    <db:sql>#[payload]</db:sql>
    <db:input-parameters>
      #[vars.queryParams // whereever you have your params]
    </db:input-parameters>
  </db:select>
```

I have dropped `between` operator and used `>= and <=` operators because `between` does not fit the pattern easily and makes the conditions in the array complex. If you want to use it though, you can.

Comment: Be very careful when concatenating/interpolating raw inputs into SQL queries exposes the application to [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) security vulnerabilities. I would recommend to use input parameters always instead.

Comment: @aled Thanks for the suggestion. Yes I agree I shouldn't have overlooked that. I have updated the answer to incorporate parameters for safety

Comment: It is better now. To make the answer complete please share also the database operation.

Comment: Thanks Heaps Harshank and Aled